# Android Social Network Notification

Tags: android

I'm about to start a social networking app so I need your help. Basically, this app just sends notification to friends when a user posts something. I read about GCM and I integrated that to my other apps.

**Sample scenario:**

1. User X signs up for an account for the first time, it registers its registration id (device) to the server.
2. User adds a friend User Y.
3. When his friend User Y posts something, User X should be notified (GCM).

But what if User X registers in the same device User Y used? What if User X used another device to sign in to and doesn't get notified because it doesn't have the same registration id?

I need your thoughts on this. I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: I answered the question, though it should be said, that though this deals with Android, the core of the solution will not be solved by your code in your android app. The solution lies in how well you build out your scheme in your backend (Django, Ruby on Rails, Flask, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This question could be solved many different ways. The way I solve it is as follows.

I have a `devices` table in my database that has `platform`, `user_id` and `token` as its columns.

As you imagine, the `user_id` is the one who the device belongs to, the `platform` helps me distinguish what kind of ID it is. Are they on an Android, iPhone, the web? The token is then the registration ID given.

The core thing you'll need to build in is making sure that only 1 person can be logged into any device at a time, so you need to make sure the tokens are all unique in your DB. When a user logs in, store a device for them based on information passed in. When they log out, or the session expires, be sure to get rid of the important information.

In regards to a session expiring, if a user can log in with many devices, they probably have many authentication tokens, so you probably have an `authentication_tokens` table in your DB. You should then also have a `auth_token_id` column in your `devices` table that links a device to a session, so you know which device to expire.

Again, there isn't one way to do this, and I had this question for a long time too.

**The core of this is building a robust authentication/authorization solution on your backend.**

Comment: This is only for Android platform

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes If it is only for the Android platform, then you can have `android` as the platform in your `devices` table. Thats how I did it before I built out the iOS app equivalent of my Android app for a social product.